# Need to restrict character input of UITextField to two characters in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am working on an app that has multiple UITextFields.  For one UITextField, I have set its delegate to self and am calling the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

to do a particular task.  However, I have other UITextFields on the same screen for which I would like to do something totally different, in this case, limit the number of characters entered to just two.  Unfortunately, the only way I have seen online that this is possible is to use the above method to make the restriction.  Is this still possible if I am already using the above method to do something completely different for ANOTHER UITextField, and if so, how?

For the record, here is my current implementation of the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if([[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]]
        isEqualToString:@""])
        return YES;

    NSString *previousValue = [[[textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
    NSString *modifiedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", previousValue, string];

    if ([modifiedValue length] == 1) {

        modifiedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.0%@", string];

    }

    else if ([modifiedValue length] == 2) {

        modifiedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.%@%@", previousValue, string];

    }

    else if ([modifiedValue length] > 2) {

        modifiedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[modifiedValue substringToIndex: modifiedValue.length-2],[modifiedValue substringFromIndex:modifiedValue.length-2]];

    }


    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSDecimalNumber *decimal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:modifiedValue];
    modifiedValue = [formatter stringFromNumber:decimal];
    textField.text = modifiedValue;

    return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both your textfields as properties in your class. Say for example this is the interface for your controller.

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewContoller <UITextFieldDelegate> {
}

/*
* other properties
*/
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *firstRestrictionTextField;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *yourSecondTextField;

@end
```

In your implementation, both textfields should set as delegate your class:

```
self.firstRestrictionTextField.delegate = self;
self.yourSecondTextField.delegate = self;
```

And when you implement the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
if (textField == self.firstRestrictionTextField) {
// Do stuff you need in first textfield
}
if (textField == self.yourSecondTextField) {
// Do stuff for your second textfield
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution.  Your answer was the most complete :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `UITextField` property in your class:

```
@interface MyObject ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField1;
@end
```

Then in the delegate method, just check that the text field is the same as the one you have saved:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    . . .

    if (textField == [self textField1]) {
        // do stuff here
    } else {
        // do stuff here for other text fields
    }

    . . .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this same method. See the first part:

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField`

The method allows you to identify which textField is triggering this delegate method. Then you just need to do some logic to perform the different tasks for different textFields.

Like:

```
if (textField1){action 1}
else if (textField2){action 2}
else {default action}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a text field:

```
    @property(nonatomic, strong)UITextField *textField1;
    @property(nonatomic, strong)UITextField *textField2;
    //etc
```

Give it a tag:

```
self.textField1.tag = 1;//or whatever
self.textField2.tag = 2;//or whatever
//etc
```

Then in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`, you can test and behave differently:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if(textField.tag == 1){
//textfield1
}
//etc
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can **set different tag** for each UITextField, and get the **textField.tag** for the specific UITextField to define the behaviour in the delegate methods

Comment: Since the delegate methods take the actual UITextField input as a parameter, there's no need to use tags (which are a little dicey anyway IMO, as they're essentially global variables).